# Integration of eslint-plugin-react-hooks/recommended with eslint.config.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I struggle a lot to configure [eslint-plugin-react-hooks/recommended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) using eslint's [new configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#configuration-file) (eslint.config.js).

Using the previous eslint configuration (.eslintrc.js) would have result to:

```
{
  "extends": [
    // ...
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
  ]
}
```

Sadly, I do not find the documentation that uses eslint.config.js.

My best try until now results in :

```
import reactHooks from "eslint-plugin-react-hooks";

export default [
{
  plugins: {
    "react-hooks": reactHooks,
  },

  rules: {
    ...reactHooks.configs.recommended.rules,
  },
},
]
```

Even if this works well, I'm sure that this is not the recommended way to configure it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: From the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#using-plugin-rules) that seems to be the correct method.

Comment: Well thanks for sharing your approach!.
Yeah it seems this package hasn't been updated in  a while

Answer (score 0):

Until Facebook (because this plugin is part of the react-core github repo) updates to use the new eslint flat configuration file, the code you're currently using is probably your best bet. Because of the interface the old `.eslintrc` config file, it's pretty much guaranteed that the deeply embedded bits you need to refer to to get to the recommended rules won't move in an update and break anything.